# How to set my Internet connection's default to HSDPA?

Tags: wireless, internet

I'm using a 3G wireless dongle to connect to the internet. 
On Windows there's a software for this dongle but on Ubuntu I can use it without any software's. But the thing is that this connection can automatically toggle between GSM and HSDPA modes. When this happens my connection speed goes very low. On Windows I can manually set this to just work with HSDPA.

Now I need to know how to set this up on Ubuntu and make the connection just work with HSDPA.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the **Internet Connection icon** on the panel. Click on **Edit Connections**. Click on the name of your mobile connection and click edit. Then under **Mobile Broadband** there is , **Advanced** option there you can change the **type** of connection, **2G, 3G and 4G**.

[image]

When it come to Ubuntu there's so much more option to choose from. Hope it help you too.

Comment: This no longer works with Ubuntu 16.04. Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

the HSPA connection probably disconnects when the reception is not good enough, but you can force the connection to be HSPA. click the connections icon and click 'edit connections' now select the mobile broadband connection you want to edit and click  <kbd>Edit...</kbd>. go to the `mobile broadband` tab and under type select `3G (UMTS/HSPA)`.